# REST API - Retrieve previous query in dynamoDB

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, rest, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I have 100 rows of data in DynamoDB and a api with path `api/get/{number}`

Now when I say number=1 api should return me first 10 values. when I say number=2 it should return **next** 10 values. I did something like this with query, lastEvaluatedKey and sort by on `createdOn` . Now the use case is if the user passes number=10 after number=2 the lastEvaluatedKey is still that of page 2 and the result would be data of page 3. How can I get data directly. Also if the user goes from number=3 to number=1 still the data will not be of page 1.

I am using this to make API call based of pagination on HTML.

I am using java 1.8 and `aws-java-sdk-dynamodb`.

Comment: What does your data look like? Can you predict the first key for each result site? In that case you can just set an appropriate [ExclusiveStartKey](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-ExclusiveStartKey)

Comment: Say the user is on page 1 going to page 2 then yes I can get the lastEvaluatedKey. But if user want to visit page 4 from page 1 then I can't. it is serialised by createdOn other than that it is as good as random.

Comment: In that case you've just learned a valuable lesson about Non-Relation DB design - know your query patterns ahead of time ;-) - Since there are only 100 items you could also just read the first `n * 10` items and discard all up to `(n-1) * 10` where n is the page number. It's less efficient, but presumably not many people will use the pagination to go to page 8 or 9.

Comment: If the table were to be recreated what would you advice can be done to resolve this or something like this is not possible in non-relational db. Also could you type it as answer so I can mark is as accepted

Comment: I added an answer and suggest you read the post by Yan Cui I linked to ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-sequential pagination in DynamoDB is tough - you have to design your data model around it, if it's an operation that needs to be efficient at all times. For a recommendation in your specific case I'd need more details about the data and access patterns.

**In general** you have the option of setting the `ExclusiveStartKey` attribute in the query call, which is similar to an offset in relational databases, but only similar and not identical. The `ExclusiveStartKey` is the key after which the query will continue, meaning data from your table and not just a number.

That means you usually can't guess it, unless it's a sequential number - which isn't ideal.

For sequential pagination, i.e. the user goes from page 1 to page 2, page 2 to page 3 etc. you can pass that along in the request as a token, but that won't work if the user moves in the other direction page 3 to page 2 or just randomly navigates to page 14.

**In your case** you only have a limited amount of data - 100 items, so my solution for your specific case would be to query all items and limit the amount of items in the response to `n * 10`, where `n` is the result page. Then you return the last 10 items from that result to your client.

This is a solution that would get **expensive at scale** (time + cost) though, fortunately not many people will use the pagination to go to page 7 or 8 though (*you could bury a body on page 2 of the google search results*).

[Yan Cui has written an interesting post on this problem on Hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/guys-were-doing-pagination-wrong-f6c18a91b232), you might want to check it out.